# How to get the result of Outlook voting button's in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, outlook

I sent an e-mail with voting buttons from Outlook in C#. The code is below. Mails send correctly and the receiver answer the vote, there is no problem in here too.

```
Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mail.To = "xxx@abc.com";
mail.Subject = "this is subject";
mail.Body = "this is body";
mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
mail.VotingOptions = "Agree;Disagree";
((Outlook.MailItem)mail).Send();
MessageBox.Show("mail sent");
```

My problem is I have a SQL Server database and in my database looks like (table name is INFO);

```
USERS       MAIL             STATUS
Jack        jack@xyz.com     on hold
Simon       simon@xyz.com    on hold
```

When the receiver answer the mail how can I update my `STATUS`.

To explain with an example; I send and e-mail to Jack with voting buttons("`Agree;Disagree`") on Outlook with my C# program (Windows Form). Jack get the message and responds to my email with the voting panel. After he answers it an e-mail comes and it says `sender reply:Agree` or `sender reply:Disagree`.

How can I update status `"on hold"` to "`Agree`" where the user name is Jack.

Comment: @DaleK of course I know how to write an update statement in sql ... The problem is how can I know what is the answer. I don't know how to get answer from outlook to my c#program

Comment: Your question is worded "How can I update status" - maybe clarify that to, how to read the response from Outlook.

Comment: And do you definitely want to read it from Outlook, as opposed to reading it from Exchange Server or a POP server? i.e. your program has to run on the same machine as the Outlook which is receiving the reply?

Comment: :) you are right:) i said before sorry for my english :)

Comment: Thats OK :) thats why the comments are here - to clarify.

Comment: Is there any other way I really want to learn. Yes mail and the program works on the same computer

Comment: There are loads of links which explain how to do this - you can learn from all of the.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item.

The [VotingResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingresponse) property of the MailItem class returns a string specifying the voting response for the mail message. This property is usually set to one of the delimited values returned by the `VotingOptions` property on a reply to the original message.